# OpenCV from source: 'make install' on Cmake for windows (gui or not)

Tags: opencv, cmake, installation

I'm trying to build and install OpenCV and the contribs project on Windows using the guide on https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib which details the building procedure.

Even if I successfully build OpenCV and contrib using the CMake GUI, the install directory is still not created even though the CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX entry is listed and filled.  Working also in a *nix world, I would presume that 'make && make install' would take care on the whole process.

Anything similar to 'make install' on the Windows post-build to invoke in order to finish the job ?

Regards.

Comment: What compiler or IDE do you use to build it? If you're using Visual Studio, CMake will create a target (a Visual Studio project) named `INSTALL`, so just right click on that (in Solution Explorer) and Build it explicitly, and it will run the installation procedure.

Comment: Commandline would be similar, IIRC something along the lines of `devenv ..... /project INSTALL`.

Comment: Great work.  Right-clicked on the folder INSTALL and the installation just magically did its work.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

(Attribution to @DanMašek) : Right-clicked on the folder INSTALL in Solution Explorer and Built it.